# Real-time benchmark between preempt_rt, Xenomai and RTAI

Tags: real-time, benchmarking, xenomai, preempt-rt

I need to compare performance between the preempt_rt patches, Xenomai and RTAI. They each have their own benchmarks but they don't give similar results and not all benchmarks are available in all three platforms.
What I'm looking for is a benchmark that will measure basic performance, like interrupt latency, context switch time, etc and that will run on all three platforms. I tried implementing the [a Thread-Metric](http://www.rtos.com/PDFs/MeasuringRTOSPerformance.pdf) benchmark, but it was too complicated for me.
Anyone knows if such a benchmark exists? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout this [Assessment of the Realtime Preemption Patches (RT-Preempt) and their impact on the general purpose performance of the system](https://www.osadl.org/fileadmin/events/rtlws-2007/Siro.pdf)

Comment: This link disappeared.

Comment: @ClockZHONG I found an alternate version. But I doubt that this is still of any use today

Comment: It's still useful, because for the preempt_rt, Xenomai and RTAI, their kernel patch only could work with very very old version kernel, hahahaha, so it should be useful, where is it? Thanks!